# Date issue in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Please see below the coding, mapping and MySQL existing column of a table. I am just getting an err

User.Java

```
private Date time = null;

public Date getTime() {
      time = new Date();
    return time;
        }
```

In hibernate mapping file

```
<property name="time" type="date" column="time"/>
```

MySQL table's column

```
 time (DATETIME)
```

> **Error:** Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1364212575328' for column 'time'

Comment: No idea about Java but if you remove that last three digits, you get the Unix timestamp for today: `1364212575` => `Mon, 25 Mar 2013 11:56:15 GMT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following configuration :

```
<property name="time" type="java.util.Date">
  <column name="time" sql-type="datetime" />
</property>
```

This should do the trick.